How to locally run GCP Dataflow pipeline as Docker image?
I have a Dataflow pipeline project with the following file structure, where run.py defines the Apache Beam pipeline.
dataflow
├───pipeline
│   ├───run.py
│   └───config.yaml
├───Dockerfile
└───requirements.txt

I built the pipeline as a Docker image following this minimal example from GCP.
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /pipeline

COPY --from=apache/beam_python3.10_sdk:2.59.0 /opt/apache/beam /opt/apache/beam
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/apache/beam/boot" ]

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && pip check

COPY /pipeline .

Can I run this locally for testing? How?

You can test your container image by docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash $CUSTOM_CONTAINER_IMAGE and then run your pipeline with DirectRunner. This could validate the packages are all installed correctly. To test this with Dataflow, you have to submit this as a Dataflow job.
